# Updating an SQLite database on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite

I have very little knowledge about app development, but I am updating an existing SQLite database (simple text changes to the html that is stored within the database). Everything works fine, but when I submitted the app to Apple the changes weren't showing when people upgrade (if you download it for the first time - straight from the App Store - it is fine, so the database must be saved to the cache).

Does anyone know how I can overwrite the existing database? People have said to change the file name of the database, but will this make the app run slower (will two databases be stalled in the cache). Also peoples data are stalled on the database (bookmarks etc.) so somehow that info still needs to be retained if possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i also would recommend you to rename the database. thats the easiest and fastest way. rename your model and set it to the standard.

i am using this solution, too. my app is not running slower then before. just test it.

please also see this two links for adding new models to your project:

[create new model version(apple)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_new_version.html)

[How to Add Core Data to an existing Utility Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528341/how-to-add-core-data-to-an-existing-utility-application)

Answer (score 0):

I think that change should happened only in the build u r tested and not in you have uploaded on appstore.

So better way u upload it again... With all testing done.