# Efficient way to store static data to perform Smart search in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

Have millions of records (ex product name , product id ) in iPhone application and need to perform smart search for the records stored.

which is the best way to store data to perform smart search ???

Comment: What do you mean by "smart search"?

Comment: You probably want to go with core data http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), a database engine. From Apple's [iOS Data Management](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html) page:

> iOS includes the popular SQLite library, a lightweight yet powerful
>   relational database engine that is easily embedded into an
>   application. Used in countless applications across many platforms,
>   SQLite is considered a de facto industry standard for lightweight
>   embedded SQL database programming. Unlike the object-oriented Core
>   Data framework, SQLite uses a procedural, SQL-focused API to
>   manipulate the data tables directly.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323739/native-iphone-database-all-data-on-iphone